# JSON parser acquires just part of JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm using `net.minidev.json` to parse a String into a JSON object. Here is my code:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(s);
```

The String **s** looks like this:

```
{dirs=[{"uid":11215,"ctime":1423258351,"gid":050,"name":"video","mtime":1423258351}], files=[{"mimetype":"application\/json","name":"file.txt","checksum":"d995a1c6b9ba371c2273f209d6659253bf457b3fa047ce62dd8274ac959c8a99","ctime":1434752293,"gid":050,"mtime":1434752293,"size":10,"uid":12020}], code=0, cookie=ODlw5jPP19125==}
```

After parsing, **obj** looks like this:

```
{"dirs=[{\"uid\"":11215,"gid":050,"name":"video","ctime":1423258351,"mtime":1423258351}
```

You can see that the parse method picked up just part of the string I passed in.

Why is this error happening?

Comment: Your string looks like incorrect JSON

Comment: I think I see. You mean that **code** and **cookie** should both be in quotation marks?

Comment: `"dirs":[...` and `"code":0` and `"cookie":"...=="`

Comment: You are parsing wrong format of JSON, it should like ,  {"dirs":[{"uid":11215,"ctime":1423258351,"gid":"050","name":"video","mtime":1423258351}
], "files":[{"mimetype":"application\/json","name":"file.txt","checksum":"d995a1c6b9ba371c2273f209d6659253bf457b3fa047ce62dd8274ac959c8a99","ctime":1434752293,"gid":"050","mtime":1434752293,"size":10,"uid":12020}], "code":0, "cookie":"ODlw5jPP19125=="}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by vsminkov:

```
{dirs=[{"uid":11215,…}], files=[…], code=0, cookie=ODlw5jPP19125==}
```

The outer `{…}` block is not a valid JSON dictionary object.  A JSON dictionary consists of *key*`:`*value* pairs.  This means your first *key* in the outer dictionary is actually the string `dirs=[{"\"uid\"`, which means the outer dictionary ends at the `}` before `files`.